# Can we get elapsed time from netstat command

Tags: linux, unix

First let me explain my scenario. We have an application using TCP that gets hanged frequently due to CLOSE_WAIT connections. From the netstat I can trace the remote host for which the CLOSE_WAIT happens. But I want to know the elapsed time (time of occurrence of CLOSE_WAIT on a particular port). If I know the exact time the CLOSE_WAIT happens, I can analyze the logs corresponding to the time stamp to find any possible reason for the same.

I know I can run netstat at regular intervals. By this way also, I can get the exact time window of CLOSE_WAIT connections.

Is there any simpler way to get what I need using netstat or any other commands ?

Comment: Have you tried using the argument option `-o` or `--timers` to display timers it will attach a timing to each open element.

Comment: I tried but it seems to be not displaying in correct format. It shows some time with -o option. I think I need to dig more into how it shows the time. I will also check --timers option.

Comment: netstat --timers -ano |grep "34007"
tcp    32255    602 x.x.x.x:34007            x.x.x.x:51515          ESTABLISHED on (0.31/0/0)

Answer (score 2):

You could watch the traffic directly with tcpdump.  If you know the remote IP and/or port you can narrow it down to just that traffic.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 src 192.168.1.1 and port 80
```